# Selenium's webdriver.Chrome() Opens just fine from CMD instance of Python but throws error when running from Spyder

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The code is very simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

When I run this from my cmd prompt (run python then use the above) it opens a browser with no issues and I can use it as expected. But when I run it from Spyder IPython console I get the following error:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
>   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process
>   started from chrome location C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Any ideas as to why this would happen? The webdriver is in my PATH and so is Anaconda

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the path to the `chromedriver` file is causing the problem.

Did you you try:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
```

(or whatever your specific path is!)

This is how I use it for my Selenium applications

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide executable path in your code, kindly ccheck chrome browser version and download chrome driver accordinly from [chromedriver download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

`r` denotes relative path in the below example,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(" your url")
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried a a couple solutions, including the ones posted. I also tried making a standalone chromedriver folder and adding to PATH. No luck... I kept getting "chromedriver must be in PATH" errors even though it was in PATH and I was explicitly specifying the executable path. The thing that ended up working was throwing the chromedriver in my Conda/Scripts folder. I can't believe something so basic worked. Thank you, everyone!

Once it was in my Scripts folder, I didn't need to explictly put a path.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

worked just fine